# convert timezone to another timezone

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime, timezone

I want to convert the date I fetched from the database, which is generated via `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and stored in a `timestamp` column type, from GMT+8 to GMT+1.

```
$time = "2012-11-07 15:05:26"; // fetch from database
$date = new DateTime($time, new DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

However this will yield an output of **"2012-11-07 15:05:26"**, which I'm pretty sure is wrong.

What could be I'm missing in here?

Comment: What output do you expect if you don't mind?

Comment: Same format, except less than 7 hours from the time on `$time`

Comment: Why not just negate 7 hours from the date ?

Comment: I'm afraid I'll not do it, I'm looking for an approach that will manipulate timezones, so I can convert between timezones.

Comment: See my answer, maybe it could help

Comment: Are you working on a website, or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to instantiate the datetime object with the original timezone. Then, after the datetime object is instantiated, adjust the timezone with [`DateTime::setTimezone()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php).

See this code, where I've used `Asia/Hong_Kong` as an example GMT+8 timezone:

```
$time = "2012-11-07 15:05:26"; // fetch from database
$date = new DateTime($time,new DateTimeZone('Asia/Hong_Kong'));
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // yields 2012-11-07 08:05:26
```

If all the original dates are always consistently meant as GMT+8, and your PHP application is set to use GMT+8 as well (set with [`date_default_timezone_set()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php), for instance), there's no need to pass the initial `DateTimeZone` object, as newly created `DateTime` objects will automatically be created with that timezone.

Comment: What if I don't know the timezone from the database server?

Comment: same fix for js?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could help.
Just integrate it in your query to simplified your coding:

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2012-11-07 15:05:26','+08:00','+01:00');
```

You can have more info here, regarding [timezones](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html) you want to use. And [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz)  for more understanding

Answer (score 0):

Check this :

```
<?php

$time = "2012-11-07 15:05:26"; // fetch from database

$tz_object = new DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin'); 
$datetime = new DateTime($time); 
$datetime->setTimezone($tz_object); 
echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
//output 2012-11-07 10:35:26
?>
```

Comment: hey downvoter !!, will you please kind enough to tell the reason ?